# Can I add a java package as Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

In my code I've used the `java.nio.file` package extensively. However, my server has jre6, so I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception.

I would like to add the `java.nio.file` package as a dependency in Maven and package it within the jar created after Maven install.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: short answer is no, you can't include parts of a new jdk like that.

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes?  It's a perfectly good question.  He's spelled out exactly what he wants and why he wants it and it is easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was a little optimistic, hoping there might be a way out without having to upgrade/change code, but I guess not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to use it, no. The `java.nio.file` package has dependencies on other source files and packages/libraries that are not freely available. You'll need to upgrade to java7 to use them.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm going to have to change my code. I've used `java.nio.file` mostly for File locking. Do you know of any other libraries, maybe even external ones, which performs a similar function?

Comment: @Chaos I think the locking is done at the native level. I don't know of anything that can do that in Java. If there's only one instance of your application, you can always use some `java.util.concurrent` locking for access to specific files.